# c++ PRINT macro linux - add date and time

Tags: c++, linux, macros

in my c++ linux application I have this macro:

```
#define PRINT(format,arg...) printf(format,##arg)
```

I want to add a date and time to the beggining of the string that come to PRINT. (it is a log, so I want it at runtime, with variables)
how to change this macro in order to do it?

thanks

Comment: As a sidenote: variadic macro args, while accepted by almost every compiler, are currently *not* into C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want compile time or runtime added to the string?  If the former:

```
#define PRINT(format,arg...) printf(__DATE__ ":" __TIME__ "  " format,##arg)
```

will work most of the time.

Note that this will only work if invocations of PRINT only use a string literal for the format string.  (ie, PRINT( "foo" ) will work, but PRINT( x ) where x is a variable will not).

If you want a runtime date and time, just append "%s" to the format and then add a call to a function that returns what you want before the arguments.

Comment: Can you please add a code sample to show me where to append the %s?

Comment: #define  PRINT( format, x ) printf( "%s: " format, get_time(), x )

Answer (score 1):

If you want local runtime date and can use boost.date_time

```
#define DATE_TODAY to_simple_string(day_clock::local_day())
#define PRINT(format,arg...) printf( (DATE_TODAY + ": " + format).c_str(), ##arg)
```

You can also use `day_clock::universal_day()` if you want UTC time.

Comment: QED, you are using a regular function: you simply cannot retrieve and print current datetime without one. Wrapping it around a macro is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Simone and does EXACTLY what OP asked for. Try reading his question. "how to change this macro in order to do it?" See above for an answer on how to do it. Just because the macro embeds a call to a real function doesn't make it any less of a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the compile time date and that you compiler has a `__DATE__` macro that returns the date

```
#define PRINT(format,arg...) printf(__DATE__ ": " format,##arg)
```

If you want runtime date, then you can do something like that:

```
std::string format_current_time()
{
   // format the time as you like and return it as an std::string
}

#define PRINT(format,arg...) printf("%s: " format, format_current_time.c_str(), ##arg)
```

Comment: @Tony the initial question was generic, and didn't specify runtime date and time

Comment: Vergani: I see the OP has edited the question, perhaps you should edit your answer to clarify :)

Answer (score -1):

If you need the current datetime, you have to implement a regular function to do what you ask, since it's impossible for a C macro to return the data you are looking for.

Remember that a C macro is replaced by the C preprocessor at compile time.

Comment: patently wrong. not only `__DATE__` exist, but the macro can easily wrap some existing `datestr()` function

Comment: ?! `__DATE__` return the compile time, not the current time.

Comment: @Simone He doesn't specify which time he wants. Not to mention that a c-macro can wrap a function call

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: I think we can assume the OP wants the runtime, not compile time, date as they say "it is a log, so I want it at runtime, with variables"

Comment: @Tony. It probably is. BUT if you don't use build-numbers/versions then the compile date is useful in figuring out which version of the software generated the log entry. So there is a valid use for BOTH compile and runtime logging. Since OP didn't say why (s)he wanted the date in the log string, we don't know